# Double backslash \\ does not work in equation environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

[image]

My problem is that inside equation environment double backslash `\\` does not seem to work as expected to force a line break:

```
\begin{equation*}

        \fontsize{12}{15} \text{1.  (a) State the Mean Value Theorem.}\\
        \fontsize{12}{15}\text{(b) Consider the function} 
        g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
```

In this piece of code, I couldn't find a way to make that `\\` work. I want element (b) to be where I draw it with red.

What is the problem with this code and how can I make that `\\` work?

Comment: That's normal: `equation` is for one-line formulae. For multilined equations, use one of the `amsmath` environments: `gather` (centred, no alignment points), `align` (one or several groups of equation, each with its alignment points), `alignat` (a variant), `flalign` (another variant) or `multline`. You can take a look at the doc or at the more general `mathmode` document.

Comment: Are you sure that mathmode is even the right way to typeset your example. The text passages in your example make me think, that only a part of it is actually math. If you want to type exam questions have a look at the `exsheets` package for example.

Comment: If it is just about itemizing thing, no exam sheets, have a look at packages like `enumitem`, `paralist` or the new `tasks` (ok, that one has something to do with `exsheets`).

Comment: Or the older, but very good at its job, `shortlst` package.

Comment: Consider also the robust `exam` document class. :)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but it is a good example of how to use these other options: https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/0b8337c6b48a7345e129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `equation` environment is not designed for *line-breaking*. For this purpose exist the environments `multline`, `gather`,  `align`, etc  (and their *starred* versions) provided by the `amsmath` package. (There also exists the `eqnarray` of `LaTeX` but it isn't recommended).

For your example you should use the `enumerate` environment (and if you want something more personalized combine with the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package).

### Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item State the Mean Value Theorem.
        \item Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]